# how to use apache storm to find consecutive time series from sensor data?

Tags: apache-storm

We are using Apache storm to do some pre-process of some sensor data. The data is something like .

One of our requirement is to detect consecutive time series. for example, we have 4 data, T1,T2,T3,T4, where T4-T3 is bigger than 1 min and the difference between the rest is less than 1 min, the we believe that T1,T2,T3 is a consecutive time series and T4 is the beginning of another time series.

our topology is like the following:
spout-->data codec bolt-->time series detection bolt.

the logic of "data codec bolt" is pretty complex, therefore we set the executor number to 2. The problem is that the time series detection bolt needs to process the data in sequence, but can the the parallel 'codec bolt' tasks guarantee this sequence??

or should we implement this in some other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Storm guarantees the sequence order in Transactional topologies.
To quote from the link : https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Transactional-topologies.html

> The core idea behind transactional topologies is to provide a strong ordering on the processing of data. The simplest manifestation of this, and the first design we'll look at, is processing the tuples one at a time and not moving on to the next tuple until the current tuple has been successfully processed by the topology.